# HTML Reloading using BrowserSync in Gulp

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I've tried several different things in my gulpfile.js to get HTML automatic reloading to work with [BrowserSync](http://www.browsersync.io/) (not LiveReload) in Gulp, but none have worked. I thought this last try would do the trick but it isn't working, either. What am I missing?

Here's my entire gulpfile.js:

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// GET THINGS SET UP
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Include Gulp
var gulp                    = require('gulp');

// CSS plugins
var sass                    = require('gulp-sass');
var combineMediaQueries     = require('gulp-combine-media-queries');
var autoprefixer            = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var cssmin                  = require('gulp-cssmin');

// JS plugins
var concat                  = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify                  = require('gulp-uglify');

// Image plugins
var imagemin                = require('gulp-imagemin');
var svgmin                  = require('gulp-svgmin');

// General plugins
var browserSync             = require('browser-sync');
var reload                  = browserSync.reload;
var notify                  = require('gulp-notify');

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// TASKS
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

// CSS tasks
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*')
        // Compile Sass
        .pipe(sass({ style: 'compressed', noCache: true }))
        // Combine media queries
        .pipe(combineMediaQueries())
        // parse CSS and add vendor-prefixed CSS properties
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        // Minify CSS
        .pipe(cssmin())
        // Where to store the finalized CSS
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
        // Notify us that the task was completed
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'CSS task complete' }));
});

// JS tasks
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/js/**/*')
        // Concatenate all JS files into one
        .pipe(concat('production.js'))
        // Minify JS
        .pipe(uglify())
        // Where to store the finalized JS
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
        // Notify us that the task was completed
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'Javascript task complete' }));
});

// Image tasks
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/images/raster/*')
        // Minify the images
        .pipe(imagemin())
        // Where to store the finalized images
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images'))
        // Notify us that the task was completed
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'Image task complete' }));
});

// SVG tasks
gulp.task('svgs', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/images/vector/*')
        // Minify the SVG's
        .pipe(svgmin())
        // Where to store the finalized SVG's
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images'))
        // Notify us that the task was completed
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'SVG task complete' }));
});

// Watch files for changes
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function() {
    // Watch HTML files
    gulp.watch('build/*.html', reload);
    // Watch Sass files
    gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*', ['css']);
    // Watch JS files
    gulp.watch('src/js/**/*', ['js']);
    // Watch image files
    gulp.watch('src/images/raster/*', ['images']);
    // Watch SVG files
    gulp.watch('src/images/vector/*', ['svgs']);
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {  
    browserSync.init(['build/css/*', 'build/js/*'], {
        server: {
            baseDir: "build"
        }
    });
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js', 'images', 'svgs', 'watch', 'browser-sync']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {  
  browserSync.init(['./build/css/**.*', './build/js/**.*'], {
    server: {
      baseDir: "./build"
    }
  });
});
```

These minor changes in the code above, should fix your problem...

Comment: I copied/pasted that, restarted Gulp and HTML updating still isn't working for me, is that all I needed to do?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out – when I started a new project it worked, which means I needed to npm install to get some of the changes I made. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem.

The problem was that my `jade` (html) task did not finish before my `browsersync` task.
So I made the browsersync task wait for all tasks that had to finish first

Apparently thats why Browser-Sync was not aware of the file, this fixed it:

```
gulp.task('browsersync', ['jade', 'stylus', 'browserify'], function() {
  browserSync.init(['./public/**/**.**'], {
    port: 8080,
    server: {
      baseDir: "./public"
    }
  });
});
```